# double integral boundaries

Tags: integration

I Have the following equation:

$$\int\int_{D}x^3 dxdy$$
With $D$ belongs to the real numbers squared. It is limited by the curve with the equation $xy=16$, the line $y=x$, the horizontal line $y=0$ en the vertical line $x=8$. I have difficulties finding the right boundaries for both integrals. If I know how to find the boundaries, solving the equation won't be so hard I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the lines mentioned in the problem:

[image]

If you compute the intersection between the lines $xy=16$ and $y=x$, you will get the point $(4,4)$. And if you comput the intersection between the lines $xy=16$ and $x=8$, you will get the point $(2,8)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes i can, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\int_{D}x^3 dxdy=\int_{2}^{4}\int_{y}^{16/y}x^3dxdy+\int_{0}^{2}\int_{y}^{8}x^3dxdy$$

Comment: Thank you very much!